elliptic pde with source term not an $L^p$ function
Consider a uniformly elliptic partial differential operator $L$ e.g. the Laplacian and let $f$ be a locally integrable function but not an $L^p$ function for any $p\geq1$ nor an element of $H^{-1}$. I'm looking for a paper or a book where the boundary value problem $Lu=f$ with e.g. homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions is studied. It seems that the solution (if it exists) does not belong to classical Sobolev spaces but to weighted Sobolev spaces.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
